# Change the order of database columns

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to change the order of column e.g. name is first column of my table and there are 10 other columns in table I want to insert a new column in 2nd position after name column.
How is this possible?

Comment: This isn't possible without rebuilding the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 - It's not possible without rebuilding the table, as Martin rightly points out.

2 - It's a good practice anyways to specify what fields you want and in what order in your `SELECT` statements as n8wrl points out.

3 - If you **really really** need a fixed order on your fields, could create a view that selects the fields you want in the order you want.

Answer (score 6):

Like the rows in the table, there is no meaning to the order of the columns. In fact, it is best to specify the order you want the columns in your select statements rather than using select *, so you can 'insert' new columns wherever you want just by writing your SELECT statements accordingly.

Comment: +1 This answer should probably explain that it isn't possible though rather than just telling the OP they shouldn't want to do this anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to change the order. In some instances it really matters.  have a personal experience. 
Anyway..this query works fine.
`ALTER TABLE user MODIFY Name VARCHAR(150) AFTER address;`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following these steps:

1. remove all foreign keys and primary key of the original table.
2. rename the original table.
3. using CTAS, create the original table in the order you want.
4. drop the old table.
5. apply all constraints back to the original table.